# Workmail nodejs nodemailer send emails

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nodemailer, amazon-workmail

Here is what I've tried...

```
const smtpTransport  = require('nodemailer-smtp-transport') ;
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer')

  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(
        smtpTransport({
          host: "smtp.mail.us-east-1.awsapps.com",
          port: 465,
          auth: {
            user: "no-reply@mydomain.com",
            pass: 'password',
          },
          tls: {
            // do not fail on invalid certs
            rejectUnauthorized: false,
          },
        })
      );
```

I'm using **workmail** is this implementation wrong what should I do ?

**Should I create a smtp gateway** if so how can I create what is my gateway address where should I get it